# Java how do I give elements in an array a Unique ID

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to programming and I've got a task to make a swing/GUI crud where you are able to put in people/animal/movies into an array etc (I'm currently doing people) and it will generate mail, username etc. I've done all that but I'm missing one thing.

Now - I want to give each element in the array an unique ID of some sort where if 1 person has ID 25 for instance, so there can't be another element with the same ID 25 unless i remove that specific element.

I use a Jframe and then a java public class where i have get's and set's for my Jframe.

Sorry but I'm new - thank you.

Comment: They already have a unique id. just use the index in the array. can't get more uniquer than that.

Answer (score 1):

***Java.lang.Object*** has methods called `hasCode()` and `equals()`. These methods play a significant role in the real time application. However its use is not always common to all applications.

***hashCode()***

As you know this method provides the has code of an object. Basically the default implementation of `hashCode()` provided by `Object` is derived by mapping the memory address to an integer value. If look into the source of `Object` class , you will find the following code for the `hashCode`. public native int `hashCode()`; It indicates that `hashCode` is the native implementation **which provides the memory address to a certain extent**. However it is possible to override the `hashCode` method in your implementation class.

***equals()***

This particular method is used to make equal comparison between two objects. There are two types of comparisons in `Java`. One is using `“= =”` operator and another is `“equals()”`. I hope that you know the difference between this two. More specifically the `“.equals()”` refers to equivalence relations. So in broad sense you say that two objects are equivalent they satisfy the `“equals()”` condition. If you look into the source code of Object class you will find the following code for the `equals()` method.

So, lets create a class `Person` overriding these methods:

```
public class Person {

    private Integer personId;
    private String fullName;

    public Integer getPersonId() {
        return personId;
    }

    public void setPersonId(Integer personId) {
        this.personId = personId;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [personId=" + personId + ", fullName=" 
                        + fullName + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((fullName == null) ? 0 : fullName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((personId == null) ? 0 : personId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Person other = (Person) obj;
        if (fullName == null) {
            if (other.fullName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!fullName.equals(other.fullName))
            return false;
        if (personId == null) {
            if (other.personId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!personId.equals(other.personId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

and now our main class to create and manage duplicate objects of class Person:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class UniqueArrayExample {

    //To remove duplicates objects we use here HashSet util collection
    private static Set<Person> personSet = new HashSet<Person>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //creating four objects of Person Class
        Person person1 = new Person();
        Person person2 = new Person();
        Person person3Dupl = new Person();
        Person person4 = new Person();

        //third object person3Dup1 is duplicate of Object person1
        person1.setPersonId(12341);
        person2.setPersonId(12342);
        person3Dupl.setPersonId(12341);
        person4.setPersonId(12344);

        person1.setFullName("Suresh Kumar");
        person2.setFullName("Mahesh Singh");
        person3Dupl.setFullName("Suresh Kumar");
        person4.setFullName("Rajkumar Singh");

        //Add those Person class Object to Set<Person> collection
        personSet.add(person1);
        personSet.add(person2);
        personSet.add(person3Dupl);
        personSet.add(person4);

        //So here after getting all Objects to Iterator and by 
        //printing those will not give you the person1 Object duplicate.
        Iterator<Person> iterator = personSet.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next().toString());
        }
    }

}
```

here output generated as above class:

```
Person [personId=12342, fullName=Mahesh Singh]
Person [personId=12341, fullName=Suresh Kumar]
Person [personId=12344, fullName=Rajkumar Singh]
```

the duplicate object possibles to remove by use of `HashSet`, because of overriding `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods inside class `Person`, if you remove those methods from the class `Person`, `Set` collection will add all `Objects` of `Person` and will remove the redundancy.

Hope this would help you.